# How do you install modules through Windows cmd if you installed Python though Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

When I use Windows cmd to install a Python module through pip or perform any other pip task I get the following error message:

**WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.**

I know I can use Anaconda prompt, but doesn't that reduce functionality? Isn't it better to use Windows cmd prompt?

I am using **Windows 10** and I am following the path to the Scripts folder in Anaconda

Comment: I installed a module through Anaconda but it doesn't get recognized in IDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Anaconda stack - and pip.exe is a part of it - you first need to activate it.

```
Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat
```

This adds the following folders to the path and actually **increases** functionality.

```
Anaconda3\ 
Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin  
Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin  
Anaconda3\Library\bin  
Anaconda3\Scripts  
Anaconda3\bin
```

Some packages can only be installed with pip, but it's best practice to use a separate virtual environment for that, not the base environment.